# unsquashfs fails

Tags: debian, binary, firmware, squashfs

Debian 7.0, I extracted the firmware.bin image using binwalk. The extracted content is `squashfs-root` folder containing subdirectories, and a separate `file.squashfs` file. I tried `unsquashfs` this **file.squashfs** file, but operation fails:

```
unsquashfs -l file.squashfs 
Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on file.squashfs
```

What is the problem?

**EDIT:** yes, `sasquatch file.squashfs` works:

```
sasquatch D1000.squashfs
SquashFS version [768.256] / inode count [-1073676288] suggests a SquashFS image of a different endianess
Non-standard SquashFS Magic: qshs
Reading a different endian SQUASHFS filesystem on D1000.squashfs
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 2 processors
Trying to decompress using default gzip decompressor...
Trying to decompress with lzma...
Detected lzma compression
413 inodes (430 blocks) to write
```

Comment: What does `file file.squashfs` say?

Comment: what version `squashfs` was used to compress it? I think there is a breaking upgrade around v4.

Comment: I don't know what squashfs vers. was used to compress it.

Comment: @Chris Down: it say DATA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `file` doesn't recognize it, the vendor probably used a custom SquashFS magic signature. I expect that `unsquashfs` is also giving you an error about not being able to find a valid superblock.

Give [sasquatch](https://github.com/devttys0/sasquatch) a try; it's a modified version of unsquashfs that attempts to support such vendor hacks.

Comment: Yes, this works.

Comment: One note: the squashfs-root extracted with binwalk have `www` and `www_safe` directories, whereas in squashfs-root extracted from xxx.squashfs with **sasquatch**  that folders are missing.